# Best edit practice when there is a community wiki answer next to own answer

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793227/emacs-and-eclipse-side-by-side) (by me) that has a partial answer by me and a community wiki answer that provides some other parts. So, when there is an update to my answer, should it just go to the community wiki, or to the other post, or both?